# regular expression in python *

Tags: python, expression

I have a bit of problem with python regular expression
first

```
import re
```

then I run a few test

```
>>> match = re.search(r'\w*i', "piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiip")
>>> print match.group()
>>>piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii


>>> match = re.search(r'i*i', "piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiip")
>>> print match.group()
>>>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

>>> match = re.search(r'i*', "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiip")
>>> print match.group()
>>>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

>>>match = re.search(r'i*', "piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig")
>>>print match.group()

>>> and got nothing
```

Do you guys know why the last one got nothing?
I was expecting iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `*` is zero or more of the preceding element.

```
match = re.search(r'i+', "piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig")
match.group()
```

Output:

```
'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'
```

**Update**

`*` is the equivalent of `{0,}`. When it find `p`, it satisfies requirement `0` **i**.

So it returns null character.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really get it.
0 ~ max?

Answer (score 3):

Despide regexes being "greedy" unless there is a `?` at the right place, `i*` matches at the start - before the `p` - as there are 0 `i`s. As this counts as a match, the search isn't continued.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why greediness doesn't affect the behavior here.